# how to parse a text file that contains the column names at the beginning of the file?

Tags: r, csv

My text file looks like the following

```
"
file1
cols=
col1
col2
# this is a comment
col3

data
a,b,c
d,e,f
"
```

As you can see, the data only starts after the `data` tag and the rows before that essentially tell me what the column names are. There could be some comments which means the number of rows before the `data` tag is variable.

How can I parse that in R? Possibly with some `tidy` tools?
Expected output is:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  col1  col2  col3 
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 a     b     c    
2 d     e     f
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just use `readLines` on the first few lines to determine where the data begins. Then you can use `read.table` with the `skip` attribute and `col.names = FALSE`. The colnames can be assigned using the first lines of the result of `readLines()`.

Comment: thanks but the issue is how to implement that :)

Comment: Does the file start and end with double quotes?

Comment: no actually. I think it is just a text file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a base way with `scan()`. `strip.white = T` to remove blank lines and `comment.char = "#"` to remove lines leading with `#`.

```
text <- scan("test.txt", "", sep = "\n", strip.white = T, comment.char = "#")
text
# [1] "file1" "cols=" "col1"  "col2"  "col3"  "data"  "a,b,c" "d,e,f"

ind1 <- which(text == "cols=")
ind2 <- which(text == "data")
df <- read.table(text = paste(text[-seq(ind2)], collapse = "\n"),
                 sep = ",", col.names = text[(ind1 + 1):(ind2 - 1)])

df
#   col1 col2 col3
# 1    a    b    c
# 2    d    e    f
```

Comment: nice one! i didnt know about scan. is it fast?

Comment: Of course! `scan` is a primary function to import from a text file. Most of the data input functions such as `read.table()` are based on it.

Answer (score 2):

I saved your file as `ex_text.txt` on my machine, removing the start and end quotes. Here's a solution. I don't know how extendable this is, and it might not work for "weirder" data.

```
# initialize
possible_names <- c()
not_data <- TRUE # stop when we find "data"
n <- 20 # lines to check the txt file

while (not_data){
  # read txt line by line
  possible_names <- readLines("ex_text.txt", n = n)
  not_data <- all(possible_names != "data") # find data?
  n <- n + 20 # increment to read more lines if necessary
}
# where does ddata start?
data_start <- which(possible_names == "data")
# remove unnecessary text and find actual column names
possible_names <- possible_names[2:(data_start-1)] 
possible_names <- possible_names[""!= possible_names] # remove any blank space
col_names <- possible_names[!grepl("#.*", possible_names)] # remove comments
# read data
read.delim("ex_text.txt", 
           skip = data_start, 
           sep = ",",
           col.names = col_names,
           header = FALSE)

#   col1 col2 col3
# 1    a    b    c
# 2    d    e    f
```

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ you are welcome noobie...who is noobie no more

Comment: hehehehehehehehe